# Unhandled error event usando node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy escribiendo un script para node.js:

```js
obj={}
require("socket.io").listen(
require("http").createServer((req,res)=>{
res.writeHead(200,{"content-type":"text/html"})
res.write('<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>')
res.write('<script>io().on("msg",(e)=>{eval(e.script)})</script>')
res.end()
}).listen("8888",()=>{console.log("Здравствуйте?")})
).on("connection",(w)=>{
w.i=Math.random()
obj[w.i]={x:0,y:0,xs:1,ys:0}
w.emit("msg",{script:'k=[]'})
w.emit("msg",{script:'document.body.style.margin="0"'})
w.emit("msg",{script:'c=document.createElement("canvas")'})
w.emit("msg",{script:'document.body.appendChild(c)'})
w.emit("msg",{script:'ctx=c.getContext("2d")'})
w.emit("msg",{script:'onkeydown=onkeyup=(e)=>{k[e.keyCode]=e.type=="keydown"}'})
w.emit("msg",{script:'setInterval(()=>{for(i=0;i<400;i++){if(k[i]){io().emit("key",{code:i})}}}'})
w.on("key",(e)=>{
console.log(e.code+" from "+w.i)
if(e.code==37){obj[w.i].xs-=0.1}
if(e.code==38){obj[w.i].ys-=0.1}
if(e.code==39){obj[w.i].xs+=0.1}
if(e.code==40){obj[w.i].ys+=0.1}
})
obj[w.i].ys+=0.01
setInterval(()=>{
w.emit("msg",{script:'c.width=innerWidth'})
w.emit("msg",{script:'c.height=innerHeight'})
for(i in obj){
w.emit("msg",{script:'ctx.fillRect('+obj[i].x+','+obj[i].y+',32,32)'})
}},25)
})
setInterval(()=>{
for(i in obj){
obj[i].x+=4
obj[i].y+=4
}},25)
```

Intenté ejecutarlo con Node en un Terminal (tengo **Lubuntu 17.04**), y tuve aquel error:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8888
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:930:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1250:14)
    at listen (net.js:1286:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1382:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/killian/index.js:8:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
```

Yo y un amigo mio intentamos corregirlo, pero nada funciono.
Lo extraño es que él no tuvo este problema. ¿Alguien puede ayudarnos?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿podrías explicar que hace tu script?

Comment: Estaba creando un juego con JavaScript, en el que los jugadores tienen un controlan un cuadrado con las teclas direccionales.
Lo que este script debería hacer es crear un cuadrado que se mueve cuando se pulsa una tecla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eso es porque el puerto en el que quieres iniciar el servidor está en uso. Usa otro puerto en la parte de

```
.listen("8888",()=>{console.log("Здравствуйте?")})
```

en listen, el primer parámetro es el puerto, cámbialo por otro.

Comúnmente sucede cuando tienes otro script de node corriendo u otro programa o aplicación lo está usando. Pon de valor por ejemplo, 8080, 3000, etc

Comment: Gracias, el script funciona ahora.

Comment: @KCJV si te fue útil, marca la respuesta ;D